# Excel - Power Query - how to create a new query based on the existing one

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have created a number of power queries. So far I have done them by merging two sources (Merge as new). Now just want to extract from the existing query. I don't need to merge it with another one. I'd like to do some filtering on the query and save it as a new one. When I click on the query and edit (filter) it, it'd update the existing one. I'd like to save the results of my filtering as a new query.

I'm using Excel 2016 (O365). Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find your "existing query" in the Queries & Connections pane.  Right-click it and choose **Reference**.

You can also do this in the Power Query Editor window, from the Queries pane.

You will get a new query which picks up from the last step in the "existing query".